# How can we change the direction of the decreasing width of the block evel element?

Tags: html, css

In HTML5,

```
<p>Something<p>
```

As above `<p>` element is a block level element so it will take the entire width of the HTML document.

If I add a css property to the above `<p>` element as below:

```
p {
 width: 200px;
}
```

I saw that the element's width start reducing from the right side of the page towards the left side.Due to which the element's content shifts to the left side of the page.

Why is this so? And how can we change the direction of this?

Comment: It''s because of the standard direction : `left-right`. ( in most cases ) When you write you write from left to right ( in english for eg ) . So when you decrease the width of the element, left side will stay fixed and you decrease from the right. You can change the direction but without knowing why you need to change it, i cannot give you a solution

Comment: That's how it is expected to be, as we generally write from left to right, but not the other way around. To defy or change this natural order we have few choices depending upon the requirement and the need of the hour.

Comment: great explanation...thank you guys...